# how to simulate keyboard 'backspace' event in codeUI automation test with C#

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests, keyboard-events

I have tried with Keyboard.Sendkeys(“{BACKSPACE}”); but it didn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx2k26ca(VS.90).aspx

```
// this sends the backspace command
My.Computer.Keyboard.SendKeys({BACKSPACE}, True);
```

You are probably sending `{BACKSPACE}` as a string.

Comment: I saw this page too, but it seems it is only for Visual Basic isn't it?

Comment: @Frank, but have you tried it without the `"`'s? There is also this page where it states the command is similar: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127847(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

It works in my Visual studio 2012

```
Keyboard.SendKeys(uIItemEdit, "{back}", ModifierKeys.None);
```